# Write text next to fractions

Tags: positioning, fractions, text

I would like to write some text next to fractions with many floors, but I don't know how to do it right. Here is an example of what I want to do:

[image: what i want to do]

In the red circle, I want to write something like what is just below.
Here is how I got this :

```
\cfrac
        {\cfrac
            {A \vee A \vdash A}
            {\vdash \neg (A \vee A), A}}  
        {\vdash \neg (A \vee A) \vee A}
        & \qquad \text{($\vdash \vee$)}
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit : In fact, I'm looking for something like that :
[image]

But I want all the brackets to be aligned and out of the fraction

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `\cfrac` (which is short for "continued fraction") even though the fractional expression you're showing does not appear to be a continued-fraction expression? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks. I am using cfrac instead of frac because it is much more readable when stacking 5, 6, or 7 floors (see https://imgur.com/UTMvQpG for the same code with frac)

Comment: What do you mean "brackets aligned"?  Are you referring to the quantities in parentheses on the far right?  If so, my answer needs some additional thought.

Comment: off topic: However this is constructed, you really want the clearance between the rules and the top and baseline of the main content to be uniform.  Adding `\mathstrut` to each line might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to achieve what the OP showed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\push{\hfill\mbox{}}
\newcommand\notate[1]{\push\qquad\rlap{$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\cfrac
        {\!\cfrac
            {A \vee A \vdash A\push}
            {\vdash \neg (A \vee A), A}       \notate{(\vdash \vee)}}  
        {\vdash \neg (A \vee A) \vee A\push}  \notate{(\vdash \vee)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, he adds "But I want all the brackets to be aligned and out of the fraction".  So here, I change slightly the definition of `\notate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\push{\hfill\mbox{}}
\newcommand\notate[1]{\push\rlap{\qquad$#1$}}
\begin{document}
\[
\cfrac
        {\mkern-2mu\cfrac
            {A \vee A \vdash A\push}
            {\vdash \neg (A \vee A), A}  \notate{(\vdash \vee)}}  
        {\vdash \neg (A \vee A) \vee A}  \notate{(\vdash \vee)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: @VictorJosso I'm not sure it will properly align the right side if the stack of the fractions grows deeper.  You may wish to withhold the check-mark until you verify it works for your application.  I am still looking further.

Comment: It works for me with 4 fractions stacked (5, because I need the last one to have an empty numerator) https://imgur.com/QoXROJB

Comment: @VictorJosso Awesome!  Thanks for the check!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest `bussproofs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\overline{A\vdash A}$} \AxiomC{$\overline{A\vdash A}$}
\RightLabel{$(\lor\vdash)$}
\BinaryInfC{$A\lor A\vdash A$}
\RightLabel{$(\vdash\neg)$}
\UnaryInfC{$\vdash\neg(A\lor A),A$}
\RightLabel{$(\vdash\lor)$}
\UnaryInfC{$\vdash\neg(A\lor A)\lor A$}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !! This was not what I have asked for, but this is what I need ahah